# Ant Script on Jenkins: resource does not exist

Tags: maven, ant, jenkins

I have a maven project, which has roughly the following structure:

```
sourceProject
- src
- distribution
- pom.xml
```

The pom.xml is building the project and copying the source to the distribution, including dependencies, etc. The source project is committed to our repository including the empty distribution folder.

Further downstream, I have an ant build.xml which is copying the distribution folder to a destination folder and building a zip. The relevant command is:

```
<copy todir="${buildDirectory}/features/project/root/sourceProject">
 <fileset dir="${basedir}/../sourceProject/distribution" />
</copy>
```

On my local machine everything is working just as expected. However, once I commit it to our repository the appropriate Jenkins job fails with the following exception:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (default) on project myProject: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/jenkins/mySubProject/build.xml:48: /home/jenkins/sourceProject/distribution does not exist.
```

I assume, I need to specify the distribution in my sourceProject pom.xml, however my attempts failed so far.

Comment: how do you set `buildDirectory` and `basedir`? Also, how did you configure the jenkins ant execution?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was actually very simple. The error was in the relative path. The jobs on Jenkins were not replicating the structure of our repository. Some details from the console output of different jobs helped to understand the relative path on the jenkins server.